# Creating unique file name for XML to XML transformation via smooks

Tags: smooks, wso2-esb

I have been working with smooks to try and process semi large XML files (170MB - 250MB). I managed to get it working and I can get it to process some of the elements in my XML fairly quickly.

I believe I am running into an issue where the output file name that I am setting in the `<file:fileNamePattern>` element is not unique enough.

Is there anyway for me to create a unique file name from within the smooks configuration via a file number increment (based on number of files currently in directory), time stamp or a random generated messageId?

Any help is greatly appreciated. I posted the error I am receiving and the smooks configuration that I have been testing with below.

Smooks Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smooks-resource-list xmlns:core="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/smooks-core-1.3.xsd" 
xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd" 
xmlns:jb="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/javabean-1.2.xsd" 
xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" 
xmlns:file="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/file-routing-1.1.xsd">

 <core:filterSettings defaultSerialization="false" type="SAX" />
 <!-- Extract and decode data from the message.  Later Used in the freemarker template.
         Note that we could also use a NodeModel here... -->
  <jb:bean beanId="row" class="java.util.Hashtable" createOnElement="row">

     <jb:value data="row/@iBookID" decoder="Integer" property="iBookID"></jb:value>
     <jb:value data="row/@vchEAN" decoder="String" property="vchEAN"></jb:value>
     <jb:value data="row/@vchISBN" decoder="String" property="vchISBN"></jb:value>

 </jb:bean>

<jb:bean beanId="myDate" createOnElement="row"/>
</jb:bean>

 <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="row">
  <ftl:template><!--<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
        <p:insert_Levels_AR_ISBN_operation>
            <p:iBookID xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">${row.iBookID}</p:iBookID>
            <p:vchEAN xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">${row.vchEAN}</p:vchEAN>
        </p:insert_Levels_AR_ISBN_operation>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>--></ftl:template>
  <ftl:use>
       <!-- Output the templating result to the "rowSplitStream" file output stream... -->
       <ftl:outputTo outputStreamResource="rowSplitStream"></ftl:outputTo>
  </ftl:use>
</ftl:freemarker>

<!-- Create/open a file output stream.  This is writen to by the freemarker template (above).. -->
<file:outputStream openOnElement="row" resourceName="rowSplitStream">
     <file:fileNamePattern>isbn-${myDate?datetime}.xml</file:fileNamePattern>
     <file:destinationDirectoryPattern>var/process/renaissance/smooks/tmprows</file:destinationDirectoryPattern>
     <file:highWaterMark mark="10000000"></file:highWaterMark>
</file:outputStream>

</smooks-resource-list>
```

Error Message

```
Caused by: org.milyn.SmooksException: Could not rename [/opt/wso2esb-4.9.0/var/process/renaissance/smooks/tmprows/.d95ba4b8-aa71-44e6-8486-adb8c9ad4bdd2660246907791429571.working] to [/opt/wso2esb-4.9.0/var/process/renaissance/smooks/tmprows/isbn-102-9780394885124-0-394-88512-0.xml]. [/opt/wso2esb-4.9.0/var/process/renaissance/smooks/tmprows/isbn-102-9780394885124-0-394-88512-0.xml] already exists.
    at org.milyn.routing.file.FileOutputStreamResource.renameWorkingFile(FileOutputStreamResource.java:308)
    at org.milyn.routing.file.FileOutputStreamResource.closeResource(FileOutputStreamResource.java:284)
    at org.milyn.io.AbstractOutputStreamResource.executeVisitLifecycleCleanup(AbstractOutputStreamResource.java:135)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXHandler.endElement(SAXHandler.java:245)
    at org.milyn.delivery.SmooksContentHandler.endElement(SmooksContentHandler.java:83)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:70)
    at org.milyn.delivery.sax.SmooksSAXFilter.doFilter(SmooksSAXFilter.java:75)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue - looks like upgrading to Smooks 1.4 is the answer... PUUID and PTIME on http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=V1.4:Smooks_v1.4_User_Guide

But if anyone knows any different please let me know too :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps could you use an other node, like row.@iBookID, from your input xml to compose your filename ?

Comment: I did but it isn't unique enough. A lot of the rows can be duplicates. Those are taken care of via a table stored procedure.

Comment: Is there no way to generate a random number or maybe a UID from within smooks or is it all just based on the information we have stored in the XML? I haven't been able to find any information on this. Thanks.

Comment: I can't help you with that : when I need to split a large xml file with smooks, I don't send the fragments into files but rather into JMS messages and I don't have to worry about unique names... could you not consider using a JMS broker ?

Comment: Yeah we were going to add JMS sometime down the road once we got it working with files. But it is starting to look like we need to add that a little earlier.

Thank you for replying. I'll start investigating JMS and see what we need to do to get that implemented.